# Android Augmented Reality overlay POI

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I would like to display an icon/image floating "beacon" on a specific GPS point. I would like to make it visible to the user, if the is around the location and pointing his device to the right direction. Like on the image, I've attached. 
Please mind, I'm interested in Android solution, and I'm looking for pure coding or lovely libraries to use. In term of libraries, I would like to have one, which is not 2-3 years old, like to most of the google searches. [image: Android AR image]

I would like to kindly ask you to help me out with some tutorial, or solution, because I haven't found anything usable yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Wikitude's Augmented Reality SDK - [more details](http://www.wikitude.com/).

It even provides "[Browsing POI Samples](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/browsingpois.html#browsing-pois)" Sample Application that covers your scenario.

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: Thank you for your comment mate !
 Yeah, I'm trying to compile one of the examples as Android project. It works, but nothing appear on the screen. Only the camera

Comment: Please install apk from samples 'apk' folder to double check. Also note that you need GPS signal in order to load POIs.

Comment: I downloaded one of the tutorials about POI locations. I have GPS signal, but I don't understand why I can't see any POI.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570510/wikitude-black-screen-with-no-location