# Wikitude black screen with no location

Tags: android, wikitude

I'm about to run the one of the POI example app on Android by Wikitude. I made an Android project and coped the sample wikitude project to my assets folder.
I've copied a free, trial licence key, when I'm launching the Activity.

However, I have a black screen and the "Trying to find out where you are" message appeared too, when I start the app. No POI appear, nothing happen, just the black screen and the no-gps message.

I tried to you the FakeGPS to solve at least one of the issues, but it doesn't work.

The Wikitude example based on JavaScript, I imported the project into Android Studio, under the assets folder. As far as I see, no exception coming, when I starting the project, so I think I'm able to open the index.html to trigger AugmentedRealitiy , but nothing happens.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You're not new here, but you made newbie mistake, describe your problem, some code, etc. nobody wants to download wikitude examples... so please, be more specific and we would help you

Comment: Hey Viktor, thanks for your comment. I'm seeking here for those who don't need to download wikitude examples, because they already know what I'm  talking about. I can't explain who the project's structure looks like, because it doesn't make sense in a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the first solution for the black screen problem. make sure you add the following codes:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.architectView.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.architectView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.architectView.onDestroy(); 
}
```